# Bootstrap has-feedback icon in label instead of form field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When using the Bootstrap has-feedback icon combined with an label the icon is displayed in there same horizontal line as the label instead of in the form field.
[image]

When I remove `<label for="bedr_naam">Bedrijfsnaam</label>` it is set correctly.
[image]

Any suggestions?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group has-warning" id="div_bedrijfsnaam">
          <label for="bedr_naam">Bedrijfsnaam</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam" value="'.$row['bedrijfsnaam'].'" onkeyup="validate()" onclick="validate()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="bedrijfsnaam_status">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is example from [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation):

```
<div class="form-group has-warning has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputWarning2">Input with warning</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputWarning2" aria-describedby="inputWarning2Status">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span id="inputWarning2Status" class="sr-only">(warning)</span>
</div>
```

Look carefully, your `div#div_bedrijfsnaam` does not have `has-feedback` class and `label` without `control-label` class